# Create wildcard subdomain with variable folder directory

Tags: php, dynamic, dns, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have created a wildcard subdomain A record entry in the cpanel (*.example.com). I am looking to create dynamic subdomains with specific folder as per subdomains. For eg.

user1.example.com will show content of example.com/app/user1/index.php, user2.example.com will show content of example.com/app/user2/index.php, user3.example.com will show content of example.com/app/user3/index.php and so on....

Please help!

Comment: If you have successfully created wildcard subdomain, you can use .htaccess in directory mentioned for wildcard subdomain to show user specific content from user specific directories. https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9191/29/how-to-create-a-wildcard-subdomain-in-cpanel

Comment: Yes that has been done. Need the .htaccess code to implement the same.